# Recapturing H-1B Time

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I have spent a good amount of time outside the US working for a US-based company from India on an H-1B. Can I recapture that time?

Edit: I know that recapturing is possible for days spent outside the US on vacation but what about when I'm working outside the US for my company?

Comment: "Recapture" in what sense?

Comment: "Recapture" meaning extending the duration of my H-1B past the 6-year mark by the recaptured number of days. (https://isss.temple.edu/faculty-staff-and-researchers/international-employees/h-1b-applicants/maintaining-legal-h-1b-status/recapturing-time-spent-outside-us)

I know that recapturing is possible for days spent outside the US on vacation but what about when I'm working outside the US for my company?

Comment: From the page you link to: "Any trip of at least one 24-hour day outside the U.S. for any purpose, personal or business, can be recaptured."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you do, you can recapture any full day you've been outside the US (days of leaving/arrival don't count). Just make sure to document everything - passport stamps, tickets, etc.